# Local time with milliseconds

Tags: c++, boost, time

how can I get current time with library boost. I can do this:

```
ptime now = boost::posix_timesecond_clock::local_time();
tm d_tm = to_tm(now);
```

But the last time unit of **tm** structure is second and I need in millisecond. Can I get current time with milliseconds?

Comment: Do you need it down to 1 millisecond accuracy? Because many computers simply do not have a clock that accurate. NTP only gets you ~10 ms.

Comment: Also, don't expect this to work like you think on windows.  Windows' scheduler only runs every 15ms, so if you check it very often, it will look like time freezes for 15ms, then jumps forward.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

look at [boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html)

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    boost::posix_time::ptime time = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
    boost::posix_time::time_duration duration( time.time_of_day() );
    std::cout << duration.total_milliseconds() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ockonal I've updated my example to show how to extract the milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be:

```
 ptime now = boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time();
```

I think you forget the "**::**" in the codes. ^_^