# C++ variable type alike Builder TDateTime type

Tags: c++, c++builder, tdatetime

I'm looking for variable type (in standard C++ libraries) that could easily substitute [TDateTime](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TDateTime). What I need is hour, minutes, seconds and miliseconds.

Thanks for the attention

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134821/local-time-with-milliseconds

Comment: @Mark - Thanks for the comment and removed the answer. The duplicate is more specific though than my link

Comment: It would be helpful if you could describe TDateTime or provide a pointer to its documentation.

Comment: Hello Rob, documentation is here http://www.yevol.com/bcb/Lesson33.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Boost almost qualifies as a standard C++ library these days, so I would recommend [boost::date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/date_time.html)

I've used this with BCB2010, if that's any help.